# Why is it necessary to say “ λ 1 is simple” to conclude “A/λ1” has spectral radius 1?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let λ 1 be the largest eigenvalue of the matrix A (which is the adjacency matrix of a graph G).We note in passing that since G is connected, λ 1 is simple (by using Perron-Frobenius theorem). Then  A/λ1 has spectral radius 1.

Even without knowing that λ 1 is simple, it is clear that “A/λ1” has spectral radius 1. Am I wrong?

Comment: This is part the proof of formula for graph energy.  formula (6) http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~benzi/Web_papers/DAM_Energy.pdf

Comment: You're right as far as I can tell.